# Why does my Gradle build fail with a "Plugin [id: 'org.flywaydb.enterprise.flyway', version: '6.5.0'] was not found" error?

Tags: gradle, flyway

When I run `gradle clean build` I get the build error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\meno.varghese\git\imc-modulemanager-poc\imc-poc\build.gradle' line: 5   
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.flywaydb.enterprise.flyway', version: '6.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:    
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.flywaydb.enterprise.flyway:org.flywaydb.enterprise.flyway.gradle.plugin:6.5.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/C:/Users/meno.varghese/.m2/repository)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository    
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I don't understand why the flyway plugin cannot be found. How can I fix it?

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.flywaydb.enterprise.flyway" version '6.5.0'
}
apply plugin: "eclipse"
group = 'com.imc.poc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.27.0-GA'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.808'
    
    
}

flyway {
  //url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imc_poc?user=root&password=password'
 // driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://imc-modulemanager.cwouijqzv1sr.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306'
    user = 'admin'
    password = 'Indegene12345'
    schemas=['moduledb']
}
```

Comment: What version of Gradle and Java are you using?

Comment: Please narrow the problem down and describe it; don't just dump your code and error here.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when it answers your question.

Comment: And since you're new on Stack Overflow, I suggest take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the official [Flyway Gradle Plugin documentation page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/)

```
plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway.enterprise" version "6.5.0"
}
```

---

Your plugin declaration in your `gradle.build`

```
    id "org.flywaydb.enterprise.flyway" version '6.5.0'
```

***is simply wrong***, and thus cannot be found.